# How to automatically insert anotation @Since on classes Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, javadoc

it's possible to automatically add this anotation with the  javadoc at top of classes? resultin in something like

/** 
* Created by "usename"
* @Since "app version"
*/

yes? how?

Comment: File -> Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Wrapping and Braces -> Method annotations, there you can customize it

Comment: Couldn't solve nothing from there, i  tought this setting would be changed from File and Code Templates, something like this:         #set( $USER = "Gilian Marques" )
#set ( $BUILD_VERSION = BuildConfig.APP_VERSION )
/**
*
* Criado por ${USER} 
 ${DAY_NAME_FULL}, ${DAY} de ${MONTH_NAME_FULL} de ${YEAR}  as ${HOUR}:${MINUTE}:${SECOND}.
*@Since  ${BUILD_VERSION}
*
*/   right?

Comment: @GilianMarques there is no predefined variable for `BUILD_VERSION` or any way you can get it from your build configuration into templates.

Comment: I really would like to have this annotation but i won't insert it manually.  I must find a way out or forget about it.